# In java , does that dead lock occurs in case of synchronized block only and not in case of synchronized method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Many of the tutorial shows code for deadlock like ,

```
public class ResolveDeadLockTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResolveDeadLockTest test = new ResolveDeadLockTest();

        final A a = test.new A();
        final B b = test.new B();

        // Thread-1
        Runnable block1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (a) {
                    try {
                        // Adding delay so that both threads can start trying to
                        // lock resources
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Thread-1 have A but need B also
                    synchronized (b) {
                        System.out.println("In block 1");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Thread-2
        Runnable block2 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (b) {
                    // Thread-2 have B but need A also
                    synchronized (a) {
                        System.out.println("In block 2");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        new Thread(block1).start();
        new Thread(block2).start();
    }
}
```

So instead of Synchronized block in this class if we use Synchronized method in those locking object , then deadlock will not happen?

Comment: No, the issue is the acquisition of two locks not in the same order.

Comment: Thanks for editing. But if we are synchronizing methods of locking objects instead of applying on Block then at a time only one thread can enter into those methods.

Comment: That's true for synchronized blocks as well. Only one thread can enter each synchronized block, or each synchronized method.